# No Sound Notifications with Hipchat

Tags: sound

My employer requires me to use Hipchat (v 2.2.1328).

However, when someone pings me, I get no audible notifications.

Does anyone know of a way to enable this on Ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I got the same issue for Ubuntu 15.04. Found no way to fix it so far.

Comment: This question has been posted in 2015. I still have the issue in 2018. Anybody found a fix ?